# Keep frequency when selecting with datetimeindex in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

## Sample

I have a `DatetimeIndex` with a yearly frequency, and 2 series that together cover all its values:

```py
import pandas as pd
i = pd.date_range('2023', freq='AS', periods=3)
s1 = pd.Series([1,2], [i[0], i[2]])
s2 = pd.Series([-30], [i[1]])

concat = pd.concat([s1, s2])
```

In the final line I concatenate these series to a longer series, in which the index values are not sorted.

I can select the values in the original index order with `result = concat.loc[i]`.

## Problem

**The problem is that the **`freq`** property is lost.**

The original index has frequency `i.freq` (`<YearBegin: month=1>`), but in `result.index.freq` is `None`.

I don't understand why; I understand the `.loc[]` to select the corresponding value in `concat` and return a Series with `i` as its index. So I would assume `result`'s index to have retained the frequency.

**Is there a way to keep the frequency?**

## Remarks

- Here, I can manually set the frequency with `result.index.freq = 'AS'`, or have pandas devise it with `result.index.freq = pd.infer_freq(result.index)`.
- However, I cannot expect `i` to always be a `DatetimeIndex`.
- I would like to avoid having to do extensive typechecking and error-catching, like so...

  ```py
  if isinstance(concat.index, pd.DatetimeIndex) and i.freq:
    try:
      concat.index.freq = i.freq
    except ValueError:
      pass
  ```

  ...if I can possibly avoid it.